# SQL Server - SQL Query to find duplicate records with different dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, analytics, datediff

I need to find duplicate records (ID) which have different dates, however the duplicate has to be on the day *before/after* the original. Essentially I am trying to find if the same ID's were used on a different day.

I am able to find the duplicates but cannot get the date part correct, is there a simpler way to perform the above?

I have been trying the following but feel I am over complicating things:

```
SELECT *  
FROM table
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM Table
    Where [DATE] < DATEADD(day, +1, [DATE]) and ID=ID
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
    ORDER BY Name,[DATE], ID ASC
```

My data is similar to:

```
Name    Date        ID

A       3/30/2018   6.26
B       3/31/2018   6.26
C       4/1/2018    7.85
D       4/2/2018    11.88
E       4/3/2018    11.88
F       4/4/2018    9.48
```

The query should only pick up names AB and DE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a website where you ask people to do your homework !! Please read how to ask before posting a question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Fourat that was rude lol.

Comment: @Fer Maybe, it depends on how you see it but the guy just said(before editing) "I need to ...." and put the wanted result.

Comment: @Fourat Thanks for the link, still new here, hope it's phrased more appropriately now.

Comment: @DaveyJones welcome to the community and good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME,
       DATE,
       ID
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM TABLE1
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

**Output**

```
NAME    DATE    ID
A   2018-03-30  6.26
B   2018-03-31  6.26
D   2018-04-02  11.88
E   2018-04-03  11.88
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/15edb/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.date = dateadd(day, -1, t1.date)
             );
```

This selects the later duplicate.  For the earlier one, use `1` instead of `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following Method

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Nm VARCHAR(50),
    Mydate DATE,
    Id FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('A','3/30/2018',6.26),
('B','3/31/2018',6.26),
('C','4/1/2018',7.85),
('D','4/2/2018',11.88),
('E','4/3/2018',11.88),
('F','4/4/2018',9.48)

SELECT
    *
    FROM @T T
       WHERE EXISTS
       (
          SELECT 1 FROM @T WHERE ID = T.Id GROUP BY Id HAVING COUNT(1)>1
       )
```